# SQLite queries for 1st and last days of this and prev month and this and last year

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have some SQL queries for 1st day of current month, 1st and last day of prev month, 1st and last day of current year, 1st and last day of prev year where output dates are in format dd-mm-yyy, but none of those works in SQLite.

1. 1st day of current month

> WHERE Data >= (Convert(varchar(10),(DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0,
>   GetDate()), 0)),105)) AND Data <= (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(),
>   105))

2. 1st and last day of prev month

> WHERE     Data >= (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0,
>   GetDate())-1, 0),105)) AND Data
>   <=(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm,
>   DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)),105))

3. 1st and last day of this year

> WHERE     Data >= (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(yy,
>   DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0),105)) AND Data <= (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),
>   getdate(), 105))

4. 1st and last day of prev year

> WHERE     Data >=
>   (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(yy,-1,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()),0)),105)
>   AND Data
>   <=(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()),0)),105))

Could anyone help me get this thing working in SQLite?
Now I'm getting an error like:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Month (code
>   1): , while compiling: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM refuel WHERE car = 1 AND
>   fuel_date >= (Convert(varchar(10),(DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0,
>   GetDate()), 0)),105)) AND fuel_date<= (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(),
>   105))

Comment: You didn't select the Month column from refuel table

Comment: Also, your SQLite dates should preferably be in yyyy-mm-dd format

Comment: Sqlite doesn't have such functions as dateadd and datediff, read the doc here instead of doing pure copy-paste http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: It appears like the column `Month` has been added **after** the database has been created once.

Comment: Those are MS SQL queries. There aren't any 'Month' column in my database. This is one of feature of DateAdd function. Anyway thanks for replies but I already found my soution. Posted it below, hope it will help some1 once.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself answer for my question. The equivalent queries for mine but in SQLite are:

```
1.  This month (eg. tday date 20160921)
    Query result 01-09-2016:    data('now','start of month')
    Query result tday date:     data('now')

2. Prev month (eg. tday date 20160921)
    Query result 01-08-2016: data('now','start of month','-1 month')
    Query result 31-08-2016: data('now','start of month','-1 day')


3. This year (eg. tday date 20160921)
    Query result 01-01-2016:    data('now','start of year')
    Query result 31-12-2016:    data('now','start of year','+1 year','-1 day')


4. Prev year (eg. tday date 20160921)
    Query result 01-01-2015:    data('now','start of year','-1 year')
    Query result 31-12-2015:    data('now','start of year','-1 day')
```